# Do service references need to be updated each time a change is made?

Tags: wcf

I've built a simple client-server application. When I make changes to the server, I would delete the Service Reference and recreate it to reflect the changes I made to the server application.

Must I have to recreate it each time I make a change to the server application, or is there any way for the service reference to be updated automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is probably: yes.

The beauty of WCF and distributed applications is that the client and server can evolve separately. Updating the client to take advantage of a newer version of the service should be a conscious choice.

Of course, during development this may be a pain. There are several ways to alleviate this problem, here are a few I could think of:

- [Use Visual Studio to manage your service reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx). If you've updated the service, just right click and choose "Update Service Reference", this shouldn't take too much effort.
- Use a test-driven approach to create your service. This allows you to focus on getting the business logic in your service done without the need for clients accessing it. Once you have "green lights" you create the client. This approach minimizes the number of times you'd need to update a client.
- Automate the use of [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to create new client side code whenever you need / want it.

There's surely more (and probably even better) approaches, but these may help you already.

Comment: Another approach I took at my employer's was to use the Interface and create the client via `ChannelFactory<T>` - mainly because I don't like all the extra clutter of service references.  In the long run it also provided other benefits from an extensibility point of view.

Answer (score 2):

It depends,

If all you are doing is adding functionality without changing the existing functionality, and the client does not need the new functionality, then the answer is No.

This is the idea behind the 'IsRequired' DataMember attribute property. If you add a new feild to a data contract but mark it as IsRequired = false then existing systems can still interface with the server using the old contract.

Obviously adding new methods wont break the old contract either, the client wont know about the new methods.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I faced this same type of problem in my project.

When I add some methods or change the property of a data member in the service then I must need to update the service reference otherwise my client is unable to use the updated things.

Basically if you add any method in the service and you are not updating the service reference then its fine your code will not crash, it will work as it did previously, but if you change a property (data member) you are bound to take a update of the service reference otherwise your code will break.